# Ivy: How can I find out which resolver provided a dependency?

Tags: ivy

I have a configuration with local, shared, public resolvers. I would like to create a report after resolving a module that tells me which resolver actually satisfied each dependency. Say my module depends on bar 1.2.+, and the public resolver provided bar 1.2.3, the report would say resolved bar 1.2.3 from public

Comment: ivy report provides this information, need to do more experimenting, final aim is to install in shared repository all modules that were found in public repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ant task `ivy:report` is the way to go: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html

Then look at the xml attribute: `ivy-report/dependencies/module/revision/@resolver`